# How to load a resource from an embedded JAR File

Tags: java, jboss, jar, classloader

I am trying to load a resource that is contained within an embedded JAR file. The project is actually deployed in [JBoss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBoss) using an [EAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_%28file_format%29) file with the following structure:

```
deploy.ear
|
|-> project.sar
    |
    |-> sub_project.jar
    |   |
    |   |-> settings.xml
    |
    |-> com/path/project/
        |
        |-> main.class
```

From `main.java` I'd like to get a `InputStream` for `settings.xml`. What is the correct way to do this?

My current understanding that the following code should work, but it is returning `null`:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("settings.xml");
```

**Update**

After some trial and error, the following statements work:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/settings.xml");
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sub_project.jar/settings.xml");
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/settings.xml");
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("settings.xml");
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sub_project.jar/settings.xml");
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/sub_project.jar/settings.xml");
```

Comment: the java class loader can't loaded resources from embedded jars, so your set up won't work. The one jar solution resolves this problem, see Eran's answer.

Comment: Not sure that /sub_project.jar/settings.xml is a standard notation. Could be JBoss extension.

Comment: I was surprised why "settings.xml" failed, while "/settings.xml" worked, but then I have read the documentation: *if the resource name starts with "/", it is unchanged; otherwise, the package name is prepended to the resource name after converting "." to "/".* Class.class does this, but ClassLoader.class doesn't. Learned something new today...

Answer (score 2):

This might be a good resource: http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/version-0.95/

The main idea is that the inner JAR is not loaded by the ClassLoader that loaded the outer JAR automatically, you need to do so manually, e.g. by using a `StreamClassLoader` to load the inner jar

Only then, from your own ClassLoader you can get that resource using `getResourceAsStream(...)`

Comment: Are you indicating to use One-Jar, or simply use it for a reference on how to access the inner jar contents?

Comment: Note that the top one is not JAR, but EAR; which means it has a more complex classloader than the standard one. EAR classloaders handle loading resources from nested JARs and WARs based on META-INF content.

Comment: @Vladimir: the original question didn't state that. The OP left out that crucial detail in the original question. Click the `edited [time]` link below the question for detail.