# How to Get List of Classpath Resources In Nested Jar?

Tags: java, jar, resources, classpath, uberjar

I have a Maven project, and I am packaging it as a single fat jar using the One-Jar Maven plugin.  According to [this page](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=details&file=resources) on the One-Jar site documentation resource loading must be done in a special manner with One-Jar packaged apps, however that documentation does not cover how to list the resources in a manner which does not depend on their custom class loader.

My question is this:  how to I list the contents of the root of my classpath within an inner jar in a packaging agnostic manner, meaning not assuming it will always be in such special packaging? As covered in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094931/unable-to-get-file-list-from-standard-resource-dir-in-maven-project-with-spring/23132283?noredirect=1#23132283), Spring's `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` [will not work](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8176) because Spring's `DefaultResourceLoader` ignores the classloader.

NOTE:  The closest SO question I could find was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602367/how-to-load-a-resource-from-an-embedded-jar-file), but this does not address the listing of classpath resources from nested jars.

Comment: `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` does have an overloaded constructor that accepts a `ClassLoader` if you can get `OneJar`'s.

Comment: What if I don't want to tie this to the `OneJar` framework?  Seems like more general question about loading resources from nested jars.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in a FAT jar. Your own answer stating it's not possible has a [link to a page](http://www.uofr.net/~greg/java/get-resource-listing.html) that shows it's possible! It's not that insane of a solution. Here's a slightly modified version:

```
private List<String> getResourceFiles(String path) throws IOException
{
    List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL dirURL = classLoader.getResource(path);
    if (dirURL.getProtocol().equals("jar"))
    {
        String jarPath = dirURL.getPath().substring(5, dirURL.getPath().indexOf("!"));
        try (final JarFile jar = new JarFile(URLDecoder.decode(jarPath, "UTF-8")))
        {
            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements())
            {
                String name = entries.nextElement().getName();
                if (name.startsWith(path + "/") && !name.endsWith("/"))
                {
                    files.add(name);
                }
            }
        }
        return files;
    }

    // return some other way when not a JAR
}
```

This version will return the full resource path of any file under the given resource path, recursively. For example, an input of `config/rest` would return files under that resource folder as:

```
config/rest/options.properties
config/rest/samples/data.json
```

With those values, one can get the resource with `ClassLoader::getResource`, or get the contents of the resource with `ClassLoader::getResourceAsStream`.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing many articles, and blogs posts, [web pages](http://www.uofr.net/~greg/java/get-resource-listing.html), site  and the Spring source code, I had concluded this is just a weakness in Java and is not possible in any sane manner.